# Как перезапустить таймер по кнопке

Tags: javascript, jquery, таймер

Есть код таймера всё отлично только не знаю как сделать чтобы по кнопке которую я задам он перезапускался [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.send-new-code-button').click(function(event) {
    $('.send-new-code').show();
    $('.sent-to-number').show();
    (function(d){
  var display = d.querySelector('#countdown .display') // меняющаяся цифра
  var timeLeft = parseInt(display.innerHTML) // оставшееся время

  var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if (--timeLeft >= 0) { // если таймер всё еще больше нуля
      display.innerHTML = timeLeft // обновляем цифру
    } else {
      d.querySelector('#countdown h1').style.display = 'none' // прячем теекст
      d.querySelector('.send-new-code').style.display = 'none' // прячем теекст
      d.querySelector('.sent-to-number').style.display = 'none' // прячем теекст
      d.querySelector('.send-new-code-button').style.display = 'inline-block' // показываем кнопку
      clearInterval(timer) // удаляем таймер
    }
  }, 1000)  // таймер срабатывает каждые 1000 msec (1 sec)
})(document)
});
});
```

Comment: Код в виде картинок - это жесть конечно. Вам трудно скопипастить текст кода?

Comment: "чтобы по кнопке которую я задам" - ??

Comment: да мне надо чтобы при клике с каким то class таймер запускался снова

Answer (score 0):

Для перезапуска таймера нужно где-либо хранить его идентификатор (возвращаемый функциями `setTimeout` и `setInterval`) и в нужном месте (обработчике кнопки, например) отменять его (через `clearTimeout` или `clearInterval`) и запускать заново.

Comment: Можете помочь с этим.В JS не силен